# comparison of number of characters in vector elements

Tags: r, compare

when i have these data (dat2)

```
CHOM POS REF       ALT        ALT1    ALT2 ...
1    121  A        AA         AT        0
2    254  GCGC    GCGCG      AGCG       0
3    214   C        T         0         0
```

I need to label every row or every CEll in the ALT, ALT1 and ALT2 .. with any of these variation SNP, deletion, insertion.

This will explain how can you distinguish between SNP and deletion and insertion..

```
REF   ALT1 ALT2
A     T     NA   = SNP
AT    T          = deletion
CG    CGG        = insertion
ATT   AT         = deletion
```

Maybe the output will be like this

```
    CHOM  POS REF       ALT                ALT1          ALT2 ...
     1    121  A        deletion         insertion        0
     2    254  GCGC     insertion           SNP           0
```

Comment: I realize English might not be the primary language for the poster, but I think most readers will need a bit more context unless the SO genetic/R folks can decipher w/o additional clarification.

Comment: It's not that difficult to understand. This is a fairly common task, so I would find it hard to believe that there is not a package in bioconductor which contains a function to do this. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: hopfully now you can understand..

Comment: [@rawr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr) some of us are in infosec and are actually kinda scared at all the genetics questions posted on SO :-)

Comment: Please change the title. This appears to just be comparison of number of characters in vector elements, with additional substitution of one of the category names. Calling this a "complex value" is not correct and may be misleading for persons looking for items on complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to just use `nchar` to look at the length of each string. This assume data has been pre-sanitized

For instance:

```
ref <- c("A", "AT", "CG", "ATT")
alt1 <- c("T", "T", "CGG", "AT")

ref.length <- nchar(ref)
alt1.length <- nchar(alt1)

variations <- ifelse(ref.length==alt1.length, "SNP",
                     ifelse(ref.length>alt1.length, "deletion", 
                            "insertion"))
```

This gives

```
> cbind(ref, alt1, variations)
    ref   alt1  variations 
A   "A"   "T"   "SNP"      
AT  "AT"  "T"   "deletion" 
CG  "CG"  "CGG" "insertion"
ATT "ATT" "AT"  "deletion"
```

Comment: Guess I need to delete mine.

Comment: Why `sapply(ref,nchar)`? - `nchar` is vectorised so `nchar(ref)` will work just fine.